# Build-time secrets for Windows Docker images

Tags: windows, docker, security, docker-for-windows, docker-secrets

In an unfortunate turn of events, I'm building a Windows Docker image. I need to use a secret during the build, but want to make sure it's securely out of the resulting image.

Because it's a a Windows Docker image, BuildKit is unavailable, which means there are no file mounts at build time and no `docker build --secret`. Build args are insecure because they would show up in `docker history`, and expiring the secret immediately after build isn't an option.

One thing I've considered is temporarily storing the secret on a web server somewhere, then curling it into an environment variable during the step where it's required. I guess that would work, but I'm hoping there's a less awkward solution.

Are there any better solutions to this problem?

Comment: what about set the secret into Environment and pass it with build-arg in env variables

Comment: @hoozcn, build args are insecure for Docker secrets. As stated in the question, simply typing `docker history <your image>` will reveal the values of any arguments passed in that manner.

Comment: you are right. But with help of multi-stage build, you can use the secret in build stage, and copy the built resource into the final stage to prevent it from showing in the history.

Comment: Here is an example https://pastebin.com/raw/0Yj4pb2V